# Scrapy crawler does not follow links even when I collect and parse them

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I've been stuck on this problem for hours. I couldn't follow the links on this site using the Rule syntax so I manually found all the links I needed to make a request. Even though I tested that the extracted links are valid urls, my crawler does not crawl additional pages. I've been stuck on this for hours. I also don't find the documentation on Scrapy to be that helpful because it is presented in a perfect word cards. Can somebody please help?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Request

from banker.items import BarclaysOfferItem

class BarclaySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "barclay"
    allowed_domains = ['partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=1&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers'   
        # 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=2&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers'    
        # 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=3&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers',    
        # 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=4&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers',    
        # 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=5&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers',    
        # 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=6&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers',    
        # 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=7&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers'    

    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        base = 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm'
        links = response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "mn_pageLinks")]/a')

        for sel in links:
            url = base + str(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0])

            logging.info(url)

            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, reponse):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr'):
            item = BarclaysOfferItem()
            item['merchant'] = sel.xpath('td/div/a[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['rate'] = sel.xpath('td/span/a/text()').extract()
            item['offer'] = sel.xpath('td/a[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['coupon_code'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="mn_cpCode"]/text()').extract()
            item['expiration_date'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="mn_expiry"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

**Update #1**

Removing the `allowed_urls` list got my requests to work. However now I keep getting `NameError: global name 'response' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working!

According to the [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) if OffsiteMiddleware is enabled then domains not in the `allowed_domains` list will not be read for a request. I know my urls are on the domain specified but I suppose the way the website queries for data makes the urls seem as if they are offsite.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import logging
from banker.items import BarclaysOfferItem

class BarclaySpider(Spider):
    name = "barclay"
    start_urls = [
        'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm?rows=25&page=1&ref_page_id=2167&ref_section_id=9720&ref_section_title=All%\20Online%\20Offers'  

    ]

    # Parse for the links of interest
    def parse(self, response):

        base = 'https://partners.barclaycardrewardsboost.com/shopping/sp____.htm'
        links = response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "mn_pageLinks")]/a')
        for sel in links:
            url = base + str(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
            logging.info(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)    

    # parse for the items of interest
    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr'):
            item = BarclaysOfferItem()
            item['merchant'] = sel.xpath('td/div/a[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['rate'] = sel.xpath('td/span/a/text()').extract()
            item['offer'] = sel.xpath('td/a[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['coupon_code'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="mn_cpCode"]/text()').extract()
            item['expiration_date'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="mn_expiry"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```